# Request for 1st and 3rd Characters of First item of listbox returns 2nd and 4th

Tags: vb.net, listbox, substring

I am using the following code to obtain the selected item of a listbox and then withdraw the 1st and 3rd characters from that item:

```
    Dim accent As String = accentlist.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim accent1 As String = accent.Substring(1, 1)
    Dim accent2 As String = accent.Substring(3, 1)
```

The listbox items are obtained from a .txt file when the Form loads and are:

A/A
A/B
A/C
A/D
A/E
etc etc

The idea is to obtain the letter before (accent1) and the letter after (accent2) the /, which works perfectly in all cases apart from when the first item is selected in which case it returns / and space, rather than A and A.

If I insert a line TEST at the top, moving A/A to the second line, the code returns E and T for TEXT and A and A, as it should for A/A.

```
        Dim accent = accentlist.SelectedItem
        Dim accent1 As Char = accent(1) 
        Dim accent2 As Char = accent(3)
```

has the same issue. Msgbox(accent) shows the correct string.

The initial code is as follows:

```
        Dim getaccents As IO.StreamReader
        getaccents = IO.File.OpenText("accents.txt")
        accentlist.Items.AddRange(getaccents.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine))
```

UPDATE:
The above code is adding a space ahead of each line apart from the first one, which is not there in the original file or visible in the listbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may or may not be useful in the scenario but it is worth nothing that you can index a `String` directly to get a `Char`. If a `Char` is OK for you then do that, e.g. to get the first character in a `String` do this: `Dim firstChar As Char = myString(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all .NET arrays, collections and lists are zero-based. That means that the index of the first element/item is 0 and the index of the last element/item is 1 less that the length/count. Your code IS requesting the second and fourth characters in that `String` because it's specifying indexes 1 and 3. The first and third characters are at indexes 0 and 2.

The reason for this zero-based indexing is that indexes are offsets from the beginning of the list. This is historically based on offsets in memory. If you think of a number line and the items in the list occupying the space between the whole numbers, the first item occupies the space between 0 and 1. The item starts at 0 and is offset 0 places from the beginning of the list so its index is 0.

This may seem counter-intuitive but it's not really, if you consider how data is stored at a low level. It can be confusing if you have come from a flavour of VB that is 1-based but almost the entire programming world is zero-based, including C#, so Microsoft took the pragmatic approach and aligned VB.NET with that. It's not a problem once you get used to it.

EDIT:

Here is an example that demonstrates the principle in action:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = Convert.ToInt32("A"c) To Convert.ToInt32("Z"c)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("A/" & Convert.ToChar(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim selectedItem = CStr(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    Dim firstChar = selectedItem?.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim thirdChar = selectedItem?.Substring(2, 1)

    Console.WriteLine($"First: {firstChar}; Third: {thirdChar}")
End Sub
```

You'll find that that code will display the correct characters for every item. Note that the use of `?.` allows for no item to be selected without throwing an exception.

Comment: @CharlieK, I suspect that there is something wrong with your data. I will post some example code that you should test. If your data behaves differently to the test then it's because the data is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. I understand that and (0,1) and (2,1) is what I had in there originally! With that I got the correct output for the first item and blank and / for all the others!

Comment: @CharlieK, it sounds like all your items but the first have an extra character at the beginning. That might be a space or it might be some other characters that has no visual representation at all. You should debug your code and test the `Length` of `accent`. I suspect that it is not what you expect for all but the first item.

Comment: @CharlieK, see the example I just added.

Comment: There’s nothing noticeable on the first line, and with the items all only 3 characters long and it being a simple .txt file it’d be quite easy to tell if there’s an extra character in there. I’ll give your code a go and let you know!

Comment: @CharlieK, it's possible that the issue is the way you're reading the data from the file into the `ListBox`. If you're not already, you should probably be calling `File.ReadAllLines` to get the data. Maybe update your question with the code you're using for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim accent = accentlist.SelectedItem.trim
    Dim accent1 As Char = accent(1) 
    Dim accent2 As Char = accent(3)
```

Adding .trim removed the invisible leading spaces..